# How do I get someone's user through a mention with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

For example if someone sends the following message:

`v!hello @UltimateDucc` or `v!hello @test` (UltimateDucc's nickname)

How can I print the user's real username with hashtag to the console:

```
UltimateDucc#0000
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to print out the message sender or the user that was mentioned?

Comment: Both would be what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), you can use a [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) to get the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object.
Otherwise, you can use [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) to get a list of `Member`s that were mentioned in the message.

Then, you can simply cast the `Member` objects to strings for the username#discriminator.